# spring 4.1 giving error when a new project is created

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am using tomcat 8.0.18 as my server and intellijIDea. After creating a new project and running, i have this error on localhost:8080

```
type Exception report
```

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [63] in the generated java file: [/Users/paveynganpi/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/tomcat/Tomcat_8_0_18_TestMvc/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/pages/hello_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:570)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

below is my HelloController.java

```
 package com.springapp.mvc;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public class HelloController {
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
         model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
         return "hello";
      }
 }
```

below is hello.jps

```
<html>
   <body>
        <h1>${message}</h1>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to google your error message `The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest` you'd find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436463/getdispatchertype-is-undefined-for-the-type-httpservletrequest) to your problem.