# AWS ec2 instance running tomcat 8 gives error: getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, amazon-web-services, servlet-3.0

**getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest when deploying to aws ec2 instance running tomcat 8 using beanstalk. Same webapp works when deployed on localhost on my machine.**

The project runs perfectly when deployed on localhost in my machine but gives error when deployed on AWS using beanstalk. I am using eclipse with aws java toolkit.

1. I have used javax.servlet-api version 3.0.1 with scope provided.
2. I have removed all maven dependencies on servlet-api 2.5.
3. The webapp runs perfectly on localhost in my machine.
4. I downloaded the zip of uploaded package from aws and it only contains javax.servlet-api 3.0.1 and no other version of it.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: [82] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat8/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/login_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:570)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

This is my pom.xml file with all dependecies:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>     
</properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring + aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AWS Dependecies excluding spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.39</version>
        </dependency>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Looks a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436463/getdispatchertype-is-undefined-for-the-type-httpservletrequest

Comment: servlet-api 3.0.1 works on localhost. doesn't work on aws ec2 system. both having tomcat 8. aervlet-api 3.1.0 is also of no help. same problem.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate, but an AWS specific issue. I got the same error when I added Apache Velocity to my application. Everything worked locally without a problem, but when I upload to AWS I get the error.  I can only assume that there is some dependency mismatch that has occurred as a result.

Comment: @daveb Its been long but as far as I remember, it was since aws has its own jars of spring mvc so you can check if there are any older version jars of Velocity inside aws api.

Comment: @user2126466 Thanks for the feedback. In the end I abandoned Velocity and now use FreeMarker instead. No dependencies, yay!