# Maven multi modules project

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I download project ch-multi from a [Sonatype Multimodule Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html). I install all parent and modules and run on server modules webapp.

In answer i receive

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
>   An error occurred at line: [63] in the generated java file: [C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\simple-webapp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
>   The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Error

> Stacktrace:] with root cause
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

This same project working in my colleague computer so. Can you help me ?

Comment: It seems a problem of your servlet-api.jar version

Comment: So do you think I can change it in pom or change it manualny, Please help me how i can do it

Comment: When you start the server, is it the same version of jetty than your colleague? Probably in the servlet library of the jetty is the problem.

Comment: My colleague i i have this smae verison on tomcat, no one have jetty, but i trying change dependencies on tomcat, and this same error appear

Comment: you can try to find out if the lib of servlet-api.jar in ${tomcat_home}\lib is the same that your colleague and in this case, check the folfer lib of your application, ussually in this folder there shouldn't be any servlet-api.jar

Comment: Yes in folder lib my aplication i havent any servlet-api.jar but i add by bytton add external jar from tomcat folder and still not  working, i doint have problem with maven single pom app

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you, Do you mean you add into {tomcat_home}\lib the servlet library? In this post explain someyhing about servlet library versions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436463/getdispatchertype-is-undefined-for-the-type-httpservletrequest

Comment: No I add into eclipse to project lib

Comment: ummm, but This is not the solution.If you use maven,is not a good solution to mix maven dependencies with eclipse project dependencies. You should have in your pom your dependency with servlet jar. I think, the problem is within the tomcat library version. What version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: If your container(tomcat) provides the servlet library you should to use this, and use nothing in your project, However, if your container doesn't provide it, you must to change the pom in simple-webapp this <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
into 
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thank you , I install Tomcat 7.0 anad at first time project start working and then a change to 8.0 and working too.