# servlet-api-2.5 jar is causing error on deployment of war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Building a simple web application. I see that servlet-api-2.5-6.1.9.jar is automatically added under Maven dependencies in Eclipse, even though this jar is not listed as a dependency in my pom.xml. Along with some other dependencies. This creates an issue when I try to deploy the war file on tomcat.

```
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest
```

This goes once I remove that jar from WEB-INF/lib. But it's too cumbersome to do that each time I deploy the war file.

Comment: See if this thread helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436463/getdispatchertype-is-undefined-for-the-type-httpservletrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I was building a selenium application. And servlet-api-2.5.jar was a dependency for selenium-server.jar. I added an exclusion in the pom.xml. And it solved the issue for me.